# Proving a Functional Equation for the JacobiTheta Function

Tags: number-theory, functional-equations, theta-functions

Let $\Theta(t) = \sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi k^{2} t} $. How can it be proved that
$\Theta(\frac{1}{t}) = \sqrt{t}\Theta(t)$? I have read a proof here https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1192&context=hmc_theses (pp.36-42), but the arguments used to prove lemmas 4.2.3 and 4.2.4 did incorrectly assumed that if $a_{k, l} \rightarrow a_{k}$ for *fixed* $k$ as $l \rightarrow \infty$, then $\sum_{k = -l}^{l} a_{k, l} \rightarrow \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} a_{k}$. Is there another way of proving this functional equation for Jacobi's Theta Function?

Comment: See pp.1-4 of these [notes](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/fourier-analysis/theta-zeta.pdf) by Peter Woit.

Comment: Typical proof is based on Poisson summation formula. Apostol discusses this in his *Mathematical Analysis* in chapter on Fourier series.

Comment: Thank you! I looked at the file.